# Select cloned element by data attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have cloned an element and added some `data` to it. Now I need to select that cloned element by its `data attribute`. The problem is that I can't find, select that cloned element based on `data attribute`. Any ideas?

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fjckls/hho6k86a/

This doesn't work:

```
var clone = $(".clone").clone(true);
clone.html("this is clone")
clone.data("info", "this-is-clone");
$(".clone-holder").append(clone);

// nothing is selected
var cloned = clone.find("[data-info='this-is-clone']");
cloned.css("color", "red")
```

> @fjckls it's just a work-around by using attribute instead of data, it
>   does not explain why your code does not work. This kind of answer of
>   course won't help community much. –  King King

I have accepted *@Hendra Lim* answer for the moment - and I understand its kind of a workaround - not using `data` attribute but instead creating new custom attribute. If someone has a "proper" solution of using `data` in my scenario then I would reconsider the accepted answer. For the time being it works so I'll leave where it is.

Comment: Just change `clone.find` to `$(".clone-holder").find`

Comment: @bukko nope, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
var clone = $(".clone").clone(true);
clone.html("this is clone")
clone.attr("info", "this-is-clone");
$(".clone-holder").append(clone);

var cloned = $(".clone-holder").find("[info='this-is-clone']");
cloned.css("color", "red")
```

here is the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hho6k86a/1/)

what u do wrong, is u try to find cloned element inside ".clone" element, instead u have to find cloned element in ".clone-holder" element coz u append ur clone element there. and replace clone.data to clone.attr.

Comment: Mini explanation: using `.data` stores the value in the jQuery's own named data storage. using `data-*` attributes is just a simple HTML attribute. Hence, using `clone.find("[data-info='this-is-clone']")`, you are actually looking for `data-info` html attribute.

Comment: @fjckls it's just a work-around by using attribute instead of data, it does not explain why your code does not work. This kind of answer of course won't help community much.

Comment: @fjckls I won't add my own answer, you can see the fiddle using data() here http://jsfiddle.net/hho6k86a/2/ I also added some explanation in the comment.

Comment: It does explain why the original doesn't work. The reason is because of the scope of the search. The original searches for children of the element being searched for, so it will never find it. The answer searches the parent container, so it is able to find the child element.

Comment: @bukko it's not the reason. My fiddle above does not change anything except changing `$(".clone-holder").find("[info='this-is-clone']");` to `$(".clone-holder *").filter(function() {... });` where I use `.data()` method to get the saved info.

Comment: the original use "clone.find" instead of "$(".clone-holder")" that's what @bukko mean.